# SQLSTATE[42S22]: (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`departement_id` = 1 and `categories`.`departement_id` is not null)

Tags: laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to select all categories of a specific departement.

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    public  function test(){

        $depts=Departement::find(1)->categories;

        foreach ($depts as $dept){
            echo $dept->name;
        }

        return view('test');

    }

}
```

Comment: edit better for readability

Comment: what is the error? Why do you echo data and then return a view? Did you add `use App\Department;` to your controller? Also, are you sure the Department with ID 1 exists?

Comment: yeah Departement ID=1 exists and  use  App\Department exists error is SQLSTATE[42S22]: (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`departement_id` = 1 and `categories`.`departement_id` is not null)

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search tells me SQLSTATE[42S22] is the code for 'Column not found'.
When you call `Departement::find(1)->categories`, Eloquent makes 2 queries

1. Get THE Department whe primary key is equal to 1
2. Get ALL the Categories where their 'departement_id' attribute is equal to 1

Given the query in your error

```sql
select * from `categories` where `categories`.`departement_id` = 1 and `categories`.`departement_id` is not null)
```

It's clear there is no `departement_id` column in your `categories` table.

## If there's no departement_id column in your categories table

Either:

- Add it in a migration.
- Add it directly in the db if you do not work with migrations

## If you want to make another column act as the foreign key

update your relationship method to reflect that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships